# Android google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps, linker-errors

I need to know if the link on contact page that I'm working on don't have error.
I mean if the android user not installed google maps app yet, what's happens when his touch the image link? Or as iOS, the maps app Already comes installed?

Comment: You have to handle it your self in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible approach is checking if the user has Google Maps installed on the device. If not, direct the user to the Play Store. [This link can be useful](http://discgolfsoftware.wordpress.com/2012/12/09/check-if-google-maps-are-installed-on-android-if-not-direct-user-to-the-play-store/)